# How to delete a empty row from a csv file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to delete multiple empty rows (;;;;;;;) from a csv file using PowerShell. 
 I wrote a PowerShell script that I use to creating new users in active directory. The csv file is created by using excel.  Sometimes there are empty rows in the CSV file. The script is automatically deployed using task scheduler  so I can’t check the script every day that’s why I really need PowerShell to clean the csv automatically.

I also want PowerShell to deletes all the contents from the CSV file when the user has been created. (End of the script)

Thx for the help

Comment: What's stopping you from deleting the rows? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I used this command.                                                                                        (gc file.csv) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content file_trimmed.csv

Comment: Is that not working then? Why not? Are you expecting someone to write th code for you?